# Fabricjs Fixed TextBox

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

How can I fix the size of a textBox in order to prevent it to overflow its size when typing (fixed width and height)?

```
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var text = new fabric.Textbox('MyText', {
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    top: 5,
    left: 5,
    hasControls: false,
    fontSize: 30,
    fixedWidth: 300,
    fixedFontSize: 30
});
canvas.add(text);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/643qazk0/2/

Answer (score 3):

You can override `insertChars` method and check text overflow.

See snippet below.

```js
// Create canvas
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(document.querySelector('canvas'));

// Define `LimitedTextbox` class which extends `Textbox`
const LimitedTextbox = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Textbox, {

  // Override `insertChars` method
  insertChars: function(chars) {

    if (this.maxWidth) {
      const textWidthUnderCursor = this._getLineWidth(this.ctx, this.get2DCursorLocation().lineIndex);
      if (textWidthUnderCursor + this.ctx.measureText(chars).width > this.maxWidth) {
        chars = '\n' + chars;
      }
    }

    if (this.maxLines) {
      const newLinesLength = this._wrapText(this.ctx, this.text + chars).length;
      if (newLinesLength > this.maxLines) {
        return;
      }
    }

    // Call parent class method
    this.callSuper('insertChars', chars);
  }

});

// Create limited text box with max width 300px and max 2 lines
canvas.add(
  new LimitedTextbox('text', {
    top: 10,
    left: 10,
    width: 300,
    maxWidth: 300,
    maxLines: 2
  })
);

canvas.renderAll();
```

```css
.canvas-container {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.20/fabric.js"></script>

<canvas width="600" height="300"></canvas>
```

*Tested with Fabric 1.7.20*

Comment: Any suggestions on how this can be achieved for version 2.4.6?

insertChar function is different is both the versions and thus the doesn't work as expected in both the versions

Answer (score 1):

For fixed textbox in fabric js Version 2+, We need to override the onInput function as follows

```
onInput: function(e) {
    if(this.width > this.maxWidth) {
        return;
    }

    if((this._textLines.length) > this.maxLines) {
        return;
    }

    // Call parent class method
    this.callSuper('onInput', e);
}
```

Note: maxWidth - to limit width and maxLines - to limit height / lines in text box

Comment: on next line it is still allowing to have new line. Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59357652/8002036) blocks **only the representation** of characters. Under the hood, the hidden textarea continue to accept the characters.

Therefore, if the backspace is allowed and clicked - all invisible text written after *maxLines* will pop up.

**Solution**: Synchronise the hidden text area with the text using the following code:

```
 if (this._textLines.length > this.maxLines && e.inputType !== 'deleteContentBackward') {
    this.hiddenTextarea.value = this.text;
    return;
 }
```